# How to wait for IAM Roles to fully propagate before running tests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have a CI/CD pipeline that builds our code, deploys to AWS via IaC in Terraform to an isolated workspace, and then runs a suite of tests. The issue is that the IAM roles created during deployment that is used by API Gateway and Lambda sometimes are not fully propagated when the tests run. We can add an artificial wait before the tests kick off but it can range from 30s to 5+ minutes before the roles propagate. We'd like to create a tool that will check that the roles are propagated before we kick off the tests so we don't have to wait the full 5+ minutes. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: i'd approach this by having a "pioneer" lambda function which requires all security groups, IAM roles etc. to exist before it succeeds, then calling this lambda repeatedly until it succeeds. To my knowledge there is no generic way of checking the propagation status of infrastructure changes (like security groups, IAM roles etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The [IAM FAQs](https://console.aws.amazon.com/textract/home) mention that changes to a role's permissions take effect "***almost immediately***". [An answer from AWS here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=195539#195539) also states that, "in most cases, changes you make are reflected in less than a minute". Note, that answer is almost 10 years old now, so things should have improved since then (?).

I'd say that you could add an initial wait of 1 minute and then invoking the API Gateway to check if it's functioning as expected, if yes, then IAM role changes should've propagated and continue with tests. If no, then sleep for a minute more and retry. If you are using multiple AWS regions though this would be tougher to check.